# Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 8000000b

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

Does this have something to do with permission issue in reading localStorage? A user connected to our network from home and launched a web app using IE11 on her home computer.  She got the following error.  She doesn't have this problem when using office computer behind the firewall.  I remotely set her home computer Internet Option to "clear SSL State" in the Content tab and "Reset" in the Advanced tab. Relaunched the browser and the problem persisted.

> Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 8000000b. at n (https://clinapps.x.x.x.x/theWebAppName/bundles/fsrApp?v=OX2U7P99gNe7AERARw2KaGARtJjysPbm1s8SmUjM-k81:1:12149) at invoke

I checked the bundle of the minimized AngularJs script at 1:12149, and it says:

```js
v = localStorage.getItem("noteObject");
```

Comment: I have users experiencing this too in angular 6 application. Also at `localstorage['somekey']` in a component's property getter.

Comment: try `window.localStorage.getItem('key');` instead

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is a bit other here than expected.

In `Internet Explorer 11` there is a thing called [**`Compatibility View`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Win7AppQual/what-is-compatibility-view-). This means that `IE11` tries to be friendly with old internal sites. (A ***LOT*** of companies had not had the time (or other resource) to upgrade their internal software stack... This means that the feature tries to determine if the site is internal and tries to handle it accordingly.

**Local intranet site is displayed in Compatibility View by default.**

To turn off this follow these steps:

1. Open `Internet Explorer 11`
2. Open `Tools`
3. Check for: `Compatibility View settings`
4. **Uncheck option** `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View`

For a more detailed description on the feature see this blog post: https://joji.me/en-us/blog/ie11-migration-guide-understanding-compatibility-view-and-local-intranet-zone/

***The other option is to include in the meta tags this value:***

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE11">
```

But this will tell for example Edge to work like it is an older browser, so I do not recommend it.

I'd probably go with this if this is going to be an internal site:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Or ask the customer to switch to a different browser if possible. :)

Comment: could be, however when I turned compatability view on, I wasn't able to simulate the error

Comment: Kind of strange, we had some users on the same network with the same IE versions and at some workstations the problem arised on others it did not... We turned off the compatibility view off and the problem disappeared. To this day I think it is an internal property that causes the problem, but I was not really able to track it down as the release was approaching and the management had other tasks for me...